# ThreeJS – Text faces draw inverted for characters with holes

Tags: three.js

having problems with getting extruded text to render correctly. it seems characters with 'holes' or whitespace in them get rendered inverted

[gist](https://gist.github.com/greg-wolff/6d464919ba69ae4a7624ef4523eb5bcf)

[image: broken letters]

Comment: Does it happen with that font only or with any font?

Comment: @prisoner849 all fonts

Answer (score 8):

the problem was with the font converter I was using to convert the font to .json, if you're using facetype.js make sure to add the `reverse font direction` opt.

Comment: https://medium.com/@joshmarinacci/threejs-secretly-supports-true-type-fonts-b896df19af2e

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a "fix" so much, but try setting material.side = THREE.DoubleSide on your material. At least it will render backfaces.

You can also try using geometry.computeFaceNormals() and geometry.computeVertexNormals() which may fix it, but may also have other negative side effects.

Comment: this hasn't seemed to fix, I tried all material.side options on front and side materials, also i'm already computing vertex normals but face normals didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

You're using `THREE.OrthographicCamera()` and its position is too close to the text mesh, thus the camera frustum near plane simply cuts the mesh off.

Set the camera further away along `z`-axis, for example:

```
// Reposition the camera
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 500);
```

```js
let scene, camera, controls, ambient, point, loader, renderer, container, stats;

let text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  height = 20,
  size = 20,
  curveSegments = 4,
  bevelThickness = 3,
  bevelSize = 3,
  bevelSegments = 4,
  bevelEnabled = true,
 fontName = "coop"

let font;
const mirror = true;
const targetRotation = 0;
const targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;
const mouseX = 0;
const mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;
const windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
const fontIndex = 1;
const materials = [
 new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true } ), // front
 new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ) // side
];

const decimal2hex = (d) => ("000000".substr(0, 6 - Number(d).toString(16).length) + Number(d).toString(16)).toUpperCase()

const createText = () => {
 let loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
 loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json', response => {
  font = response
  textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( text, {
   font: font,
   size: size,
   height: height,
   curveSegments: curveSegments,
   bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
   bevelSize: bevelSize,
   bevelEnabled: true
  });

  textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
  //textGeo.computeVertexNormals();

  var centerOffset = -0.5 * ( textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x );
  textGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( textGeo );
  textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, materials );
  textMesh1.position.x = centerOffset;
  textMesh1.position.z = 0;
  textMesh1.rotation.x = 0;
  textMesh1.rotation.y = Math.PI * 2;
  group.add( textMesh1 );
 });
}

const refreshText = () => {
 group.remove( textMesh1 );
 createText();
}

init();
animate();

function init() {
  // Create a scene which will hold all our meshes to be rendered
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Create and position a camera
  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    // 60, // Field of view
    // window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // Aspect ratio
    window.innerWidth / -8,
    window.innerWidth / 8,
    window.innerHeight / 8,
    window.innerHeight / -8,
    0.1, // Near clipping pane
    1000 // Far clipping pane
  );
  // Reposition the camera
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 500);
  // Point the camera at a given coordinate
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 15, 0));

  // Add orbit control
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.target.set(0, -0.2, -0.2);
  controls.update();

  // Add an ambient lights
  ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
  scene.add(ambient);

  // Add a point light that will cast shadows
  point = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
  point.position.set(25, 50, 25);
  point.castShadow = true;
  point.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  point.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  scene.add(point);

 group = new THREE.Group();
 group.position.y = 0;
 scene.add( group );

 createText();

  // Create a renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  // Set size
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Set color
  renderer.setClearColor(0xf8a5c2);
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;
  // Enable shadow mapping
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

  // Append to the document
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  // Add resize listener
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

  // Enable FPS stats
  stats = new Stats();
 container.appendChild(stats.dom);

 var gui = new dat.GUI({
    height: 5 * 32 - 1
});
let params = {
  'curveSegments': 4,
  'bevelThickness': 1,
  'bevelSize': 1.5,
  'bevelSegments': 3
}
gui.add(params, 'curveSegments', 0, 10).onChange(val => {
 curveSegments = val
 refreshText()
})
gui.add(params, 'bevelThickness', 0, 10).onChange(val => {
 bevelThickness = val
 refreshText()
})
gui.add(params, 'bevelSize', 0, 10).onChange(val => {
 bevelSize = val
 refreshText()
})
gui.add(params, 'bevelSegments', 0, 10).onChange(val => {
 bevelSegments = val
 refreshText()
})
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // Re-render scene
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Update stats
  stats.update();
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.2/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: seems to be independent of the orthographic camera:

Comment: you can see how it interprets the inner circles as the spots that should be filled on this default front view [pic](https://i.imgur.com/RUCMB0E.png)

Comment: @GregWolff does it mean that it doesn't work with your font only?

Comment: @GregWolff But not with `helvetiker_bold.typeface.json`, that I've used in the code snippet.